Design for MinIO for storing images and video files that user generates
I have a mobile application that allows users to generate pictures using camera of their phone. I want to store that in a bucket so I can use API to query it when required. How would I store this in MinIO? Should I store the images for all users in the same bucket and how would I query a image/video for a particular user uid?
Does MinIO allow you to store a file/image with a 'id' you can query later?
